# Is it sensible to say "Engineers find problems to solutions"?

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning

A teacher was telling us about engineering the other day and she said that engineers solve problems. I thought about it and came up with "Engineers find problems to solutions".

**The sense of the statement:**
Suppose something has a fault in it but, it is used as a solution to another problem. An engineers happens to find that problem in that solution.

So, would be correct to say "Engineers find problems to solutions"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The phrase "Engineers find problems to solutions" is *mostly* sensible. It is clear that it comes from the normal phrase of "... find solutions to problems", which is what makes it kind of humorous.

**However** typically problems are found **in** something.  Therefore a more natural way to say this is:

> Engineers find problems in solutions.

This keeps a similar humor, because the common phrase is to solve problems. It changes the "original" sentence more than your suggestion, but is more idiomatic.

At the end of the day, the differences between the two options are stylistic, and either could work.